# Tap navigation bar to scroll to top

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiwebview, uinavigationbar

I have a really long UIWebView, and I need to add a way for the user to tap the UINavigationBar to scroll to top (something like the Facebook app, where it's little glow when you tap).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS5, you can now access the UIScrollView directly, allowing you to scroll to top.

```
[webView.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:animated:]
```

That should take care of everything that you need.

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript to scroll the web view to the top. You could execute the javascript from the Objective-C side using

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script
```

Comment: Actually that I knew, what I'm mainly struggling with is how I can make it do that when I tap the UINavigationBar?

Comment: As lyonanderson said, you could create a custom titleView for your navigation bar to handle the touch events and execute the javascript in your webView

Comment: Alternatively you could add a UINavigationBar category which overrides the touches methods to integrate your custom code to talk to the webView

Comment: How exactly would I do that? :)

Comment: Decent solution. The smoother way to do it using the UIWebView's internal UIScrollView and scrolling it to the top, although it's a bit hacky.